# Instalar Kali Linux con Rufus en USB

Tags: linux, kali-linux

###### Hola a todos,

he intentado durante estos últimos días instalar Kali Linux en una unidad de memoria USB (64GB) con el programa [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/), pero al cabo de varias horas, cuando está terminando el formateo, me da un error diciendo que no se detecta el USB. Este error no me ha sucedido con otros USB, de menor capacidad. He probado con los sistemas de archivos FAT32 y NTFS.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: debes validar si el dispositivo se marca como usb o disco externo... ya que algunos fabricantes lo colocan como disco extraible y no es del todo adecuada para crear unidades de booteo, cambiar el formateo no hace ninguna diferencia ya que no afecta las tablas, solo borra el contenido de la partición primaria visible. en linux usa el comando `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sd*** ` para pasar todos los bits a 0 y luego formatea a `fat32` ya `ntfs` no es compatible con uefi...

Answer (score 1):

Deberias de probar con exFAT recuerda que tienes que especificar el SO destino para evitar problemas a la hora de realizar el boot del sistema operativo.